# cross validation in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, cross-validation, apache-spark-ml

I used cross validation to train a linear regression model using the following code:

```python
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator

lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=maxIteration)
modelEvaluator=RegressionEvaluator()
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[lr])
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(lr.regParam, [0.1, 0.01]).addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, [0, 1]).build()

crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline,
                          estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                          evaluator=modelEvaluator,
                          numFolds=3)

cvModel = crossval.fit(training)
```

now I want to draw the roc curve, I used the following code but I get this error:

*'LinearRegressionTrainingSummary' object has no attribute 'areaUnderROC'*

```python
trainingSummary = cvModel.bestModel.stages[-1].summary
trainingSummary.roc.show()
print("areaUnderROC: " + str(trainingSummary.areaUnderROC))
```

I also want to check the objectiveHistory at each itaration, I know that I can get it at the end

```python
print("numIterations: %d" % trainingSummary.totalIterations)
print("objectiveHistory: %s" % str(trainingSummary.objectiveHistory))
```

but I want to get it at each iteration, how can I do this?

Moreover I want to evaluate the model on the test data, how can I do that?

```python
prediction = cvModel.transform(test)
```

I know for the training data set I can write:

```python
print("RMSE: %f" % trainingSummary.rootMeanSquaredError)
print("r2: %f" % trainingSummary.r2)
```

but how can I get these metrics for testing data set?

Comment: Satisfied with the answer?

Comment: thanks, your answer is very helpful, just one question, how can I learn about pyspark ml library ?  other than the Spark online documentation?

Comment: Not many sources around, plus that the API changes very frequently. This may be useful (Scala): https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-mllib/spark-mllib-pipelines.html

Comment: Plus LOTS of headaches & undocumented counter-intuitive features, especially for Pyspark - see my blog post https://www.nodalpoint.com/spark-classification/

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) The area under the ROC curve (AUC) is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) only for **binary classification**, hence you cannot use it for regression tasks, as you are trying to do here.

2) The `objectiveHistory` for each iteration is only available when the `solver` argument in the regression is `l-bfgs` ([documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegressionTrainingSummary.objectiveHistory)); here is a toy example:

```python
spark.version
# u'2.1.1'

from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder

dataset = spark.createDataFrame(
        [(Vectors.dense([0.0]), 0.2),
         (Vectors.dense([0.4]), 1.4),
         (Vectors.dense([0.5]), 1.9),
         (Vectors.dense([0.6]), 0.9),
         (Vectors.dense([1.2]), 1.0)] * 10,
         ["features", "label"])

lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=5, solver="l-bfgs") # solver="l-bfgs" here

modelEvaluator=RegressionEvaluator()
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[lr])
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(lr.regParam, [0.1, 0.01]).addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, [0, 1]).build()

crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=lr,
                          estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                          evaluator=modelEvaluator,
                          numFolds=3)

cvModel = crossval.fit(dataset)

trainingSummary = cvModel.bestModel.summary

trainingSummary.totalIterations
# 2
trainingSummary.objectiveHistory # one value for each iteration
# [0.49, 0.4511834723904831]
```

3) You have already defined a `RegressionEvaluator` which you can use for evaluating your test set but, if used without arguments, it assumes the RMSE metric; here is a way to define evaluators with different metrics and apply them to your test set (continuing the code from above):

```python
test = spark.createDataFrame(
        [(Vectors.dense([0.0]), 0.2),
         (Vectors.dense([0.4]), 1.1),
         (Vectors.dense([0.5]), 0.9),
         (Vectors.dense([0.6]), 1.0)],
        ["features", "label"])

modelEvaluator.evaluate(cvModel.transform(test))  # rmse by default, if not specified
# 0.35384585061028506

eval_rmse = RegressionEvaluator(metricName="rmse")
eval_r2 = RegressionEvaluator(metricName="r2")

eval_rmse.evaluate(cvModel.transform(test)) # same as above
# 0.35384585061028506

eval_r2.evaluate(cvModel.transform(test))
# -0.001655087952929124
```