# Cross validate in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, pyspark-pandas

I have a need for cross_validate in pyspark. I have unerdstood the code with python but can anyone help me with the pyspark coding of this?

Python code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

cv_set = cross_validate(gamma_cdf(), X['input_col'], X['target'], cv = 5, scoring = 'neg_root_mean_squared_error', return_estimator = True)
```

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420112/cross-validation-in-pyspark answer your question ?

Comment: @DKNY, I am not sure what to use for the scoring part. as I am using neg_root_mean_squared_error.